# Как запретить доступ к папке кроме некоторых файлов в nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Запретил доступ к папке /engine/ вот так:

```
location ^~ /engine/ {
  deny all;
}
```

Но есть файл к которому нужно открыть прямой доступ, он находится здесь: /engine/modules/donor_bot/donor_bot_api.php

Пробовал сделать так:

```
location ^~ /engine/modules/donor_bot/donor_bot_api.php {
  allow all;
}
```

Но так при вызове файл загружается на компьютер. Как сделать что бы он исполнялся?

Или может я изначально не правильно к вопросу начал подходить? Может есть более правильное и элегантное решение?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/450154/nginx-disallow-access-to-a-folder-except-some-subfolders

Comment: Если честно ничего не понял, если Вы понимаете как сделать, объясните пожалуйста на моём примере.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ^~ /engine/modules/donor_bot/donor_bot_api.php {
  allow all;
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```